# Mysql insert statement not inserting data in db

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, forms

My MySQL query should insert data input from form. No error is given.  I see absolutely nothing wrong this code. I have used this code before for other tables and it works properly. Please ignore the isset for update. That is for something else. writerID, illustratorID and publisherName are foreign keys from different tables. could that be the issue?

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "graphicnoveldb";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// get results from database

if(isset($_POST['update'])){
    $UpdateQuery = "Update graphicnovel Set
                    graphicNovelTitle='$_POST[graphicnoveltitle]',
                    genre='$_POST[genre]',
                    synopsis='$_POST[synopsis]',
                    review='$_POST[review]',
                    rating='$_POST[rating]',
                    writerID='$_POST[writerID]',
                    illustratorID='$_POST[illustratorID]',
                    coverPage='$_POST[coverpage]'
                    Where graphicNovelTitle='$_POST[hidden]'";
    mysqli_query($conn,$UpdateQuery);

};


if(isset($_POST['add'])){
    $AddQuery = "Insert into graphicnovel (graphicNovelTitle, genre, synopsis, review, rating, writerID, illustratorID, publisherName, datePublished, coverPage)
                Values('$_POST[ugraphicnoveltitle]',
                      '$_POST[ugenre]',
                      '$_POST[usynopsis]',
                      '$_POST[ureview]',
                      '$_POST[urating]',
                      '$_POST[uwriterID]',
                      '$_POST[uillustratorID]',
                      '$_POST[upublishername]',
                      '$_POST[udatepublished]',
                      '$_POST[ucoverpage]')";
    mysqli_query($conn,$AddQuery);

};



$sql="SELECT * FROM graphicnovel";

$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);



echo "<table>";



echo "<form action = ModifyGraphicNovel.php method =post>";

echo"<tr><th>New Graphic Novel Title</th>";
echo '<td><input type=text name= ugraphicnoveltitle></td></tr>';

echo"<tr><th>New Genre</th>";
echo '<td><input type=text name= ugenre></td></tr>';

echo"<tr><th>New Synopsis</th>";
echo '<td><textarea name= usynopsis  rows = 5 cols = 70 border =5 value=></textarea></tr>';

echo"<tr><th>New Review</th>";
echo '<td><textarea name= ureview  rows = 5 cols = 70 border =5 value=></textarea></tr>';

echo"<tr><th>New Rating</th>";
echo '<td><input type=text name= urating></td></tr>';

echo"<tr><th>New Writer ID</th>";
echo '<td><input type=text name= uwriterID></td></tr>';

echo"<tr><th>New Illustrator ID</th>";
echo '<td><input type=text name= uillustratorID></td></tr>';

echo"<tr><th>New Publisher Name</th>";
echo '<td><input type=text name= upublishername></td></tr>';

echo"<tr><th>New Date Published</th>";
echo '<td><input type=date name= udatepublished></td></tr>';

echo"<tr><th>New Coverpage</th>";
echo '<td><input type=text name= ucoverpage></td></tr>';



echo '<tr><td>' . "<input type = submit name=add value=add" . ' </td></tr>';

echo "</form>";
echo "</table>";
// close table>


$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: `"I see absolutely nothing wrong this code"` - You mean aside from the glaring SQL injection vulnerabilities and the complete lack of error checking?

Comment: @David `if ($conn->connect_error) { die` -- well, not **complete** but anyway...

Comment: @AlanMachado: True, the OP does check for an error on the database interaction that's *least* likely to fail.  But then never checks for errors when executing whatever code any user feels like executing.

Comment: @David yeah I give you that. And then, there's the possibility of php.ini leaving error unyielding.

Comment: do u know wat check I can use for $AddQuery? and how?

Comment: nevermind the foreign key was the issue. solved it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You have to use quotes around the array keys as stated above, and also always use curly braces around arrays when they are in a quoted string.
2. Should prevent SQL Injection using escaping, or even better, bind parameters.  Which would make the first problem a bit easier also...

```php
if(isset($_POST['add'])){

  $AddQuery = $conn->prepare("Insert into graphicnovel (graphicNovelTitle, 
             genre, synopsis, review, rating, writerID, illustratorID,
             publisherName, datePublished, coverPage) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
  $addQuery->bind_param($_POST['ugraphicnoveltitle'],
                  $_POST['ugenre'],
                  $_POST['usynopsis'],
                  $_POST['ureview'],
                  $_POST['urating'],
                  $_POST['uwriterID'],
                  $_POST['uillustratorID'],
                  $_POST['upublishername'],
                  $_POST['udatepublished'],
                  $_POST['ucoverpage']);

  $addQuery->execute();

  printf("%d Row inserted.\n", $addQuery->affected_rows);
  $addQuery->close();


}
```